# Java HttpURLConnection blocked at work, but not Firefox

Tags: java, firefox, proxy, httpurlconnection, blocked

*Good afternoon,*

I have an issue concerning an HttpURLConnection and the internet restrictions at work...

**What I am trying to do:**

I am trying to write a program that connects to the site http://www.epexspot.com and reads the peak and base product price histories for electricity.

---

**Why I am trying to do this:**

Up to now, the collection of the prices has been done manually, which is a tedious procedure.
Thus, I wanted to automate this with a little program.

---

**What I have done so far:**

I wrote a Java (JDK7u21) program making use of an HttpURLConnection, trying to contact the homepage and fetching the sent response; here you can see pretty much what I wrote:

HttpConnector.java

```
package network;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class HttpConnector {
String urlParameters, method;
URL url;
HttpURLConnection conn;
BufferedReader in;

public HttpConnector(String host, String method) throws IOException{
    if(!host.startsWith("http://") && !host.startsWith("https://"))
        host = "http://" + host;

    this.method = method;
    urlParameters = "";
    url = new URL(host);
}

public HttpConnector(String host, String method, String parameters) throws IOException{
    if(!host.startsWith("http://") && !host.startsWith("https://"))
        host = "http://" + host;

    this.method = method;
    urlParameters = parameters;
    url = new URL(host);
}

public void openConnection() throws IOException{
    conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    conn.setRequestMethod(method);
    conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:21.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/21.0");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Host", url.getHost());
    conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "keep-alive");
    if(urlParameters!="" && urlParameters!=null) 
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", Integer.toString(urlParameters.getBytes().length));
    conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "de-de,de;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.5,en;q=0.3");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "deflate");/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8");
    conn.setUseCaches(false);
    conn.setDoInput(true);
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
}

public void sendRequest() throws IOException{
    if(method == "POST"){
        DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
        out.writeBytes(urlParameters);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    }
}

public ArrayList<String> read() throws IOException{
    if(conn.getResponseCode()>226 || conn.getResponseCode()<200){
        try{
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getErrorStream()));
        }catch(NullPointerException e){
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
        }
    }else{
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
    }
    ArrayList<String> resp = new ArrayList<String>();
    String respTmp;

    while((respTmp=in.readLine())!=null){
        resp.add(respTmp);
    }
    return resp;
}

public void close(){
    if(conn!=null) conn.disconnect();
}

public ArrayList<String> communicate() throws IOException{
    ArrayList<String> resp = new ArrayList<String>();
    try{
        openConnection();
        sendRequest();
        resp=read();
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace(System.err);
    }finally{
        close();
    }
    return resp;
}

}
```

Main.java

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import network.HttpConnector;


public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try{
            File f = new File("response.html");
            if(!f.exists()) f.createNewFile();

//          String host = "http://www.epexspot.com/en/market-data/auction/auction-table/2013-05-28/DE";
// this is where I actually need to go; google.at is merely for testing purposes
            String host = "www.google.at";
            String method = "GET";

            ArrayList<String> response = new ArrayList<String>();
            HttpConnector conn = new HttpConnector(host,method);
            response = conn.communicate();

            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(f);
            BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fw);

            for(String resp : response){
                System.out.println(resp);
                out.write(resp+"\n");
            }

            out.flush();
            out.close();
            fw.close();
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

*Short explanation:*
The HttpConnector connects to a given Host with given method (primarily POST or GET) and given URL parameters (which i don't use, though).
It sets some Request Properties (such as the User-Agent, ...) and then tries to read the response (via the InputStream; if the response status says it has been unsuccessful, via the ErrorStream).

Main is calling the HttpConnector with a specific URL (e.g. www.epexspot.com/en/) and a specific method (either POST or GET).
It then reads the response of the connection and prints it to the console aswell as a file (response.html).

---

**Where my problem is:**

Here at work, the traffic is kind of regulated, meaning that some homepages are blocked (just the way that they are blocked at school). So, of course if I feed some URL for a social media platform to my little program, it will spit out something like "**Error 403 - contents of the page have been blocked. if you need this page for work, please contact your admin**".

This, for example happens to me when I try to reach the desired page, *epexspot.com* - **BUT**:
the page is **NOT** blocked, when I am calling it with the ordinary *Mozilla Firefox (v21)*.
On some pages, my program will work just fine, but not on most (e.g. www.google.at, www.ivb.at work just fine... whereas most other pages don't)

I have already tried to make my program act like it was Firefox concerning the Request Properties, but it has lead to no result up to now...
Am I missing some Request Property or setting that could make the internet regulation software block my program, but not Mozilla Firefox?

---

**So, my primary question is:**

What could be the reason that my program keeps being blocked, while Firefox won't experience a blocking level anywhere near it?

I will try to contact the network admins at work, and hope that they have a solution for my program not being blocked all the time anymore, but I still wonder what could make such a significant difference between Firefox and my program.

---

*Thanks in advance*

Comment: is firefox configured to use a proxy?

Comment: ah, yeah, of course... this was of course too obvious for me to see;
it is indeed set to auto-configure

Comment: thanks, @jtahlborn for showing me the obvious which i failed to see!

Comment: no problem, sometimes the obvious is the hardest thing to see. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, the answer is as simple as it could be...

Firefox has been configured to use the auto-configured proxy server, so here is what I did:

I had my websites open in Firefox, did the `netstat -an | find "EST"` trick, figured out what the proxy's address (and port) was and made my program use them with the lines

`System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", proxyAddress);`
and
`System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "8080");`

That fixed the problem for me...

Thanks, jtahlborn for this hint!

**Edit:**

Making use of the ProxySelector also works pretty well; should you need it, follow this link: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/net/proxies.html